# How to run the same parameter to 22 similar databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been pulling data from a single database that stores the data for 22 facilities together. The database has now been redesigned and there are 22 separate databases (similar) for each of the facilities that we have. How can use the same code and run it against all these databases at the same time? Like, how can I pass the same parameter and pull data from all 22 databases?

Comment: Are all of these databases on the same server or are they spread out over the network?

Comment: If your data has been segregated, then so now will your queries. Now that they're in different tables, and databases, you'll have to query each table/database and use a `JOIN` or `UNION` query of some kind. The query will also no automatically scale if you were to increase the number of databases; all your queries would have to be amended to cater for the new database.

Comment: Can you post your sample query considering any of the database?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You may also benefit from [this helpful article on what is considered necessary for an SQL question](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: All databases are on the same server.

Comment: First, you don't run "parameters". You run scripts, execute statements, etc. Use terminology that everyone can understand. Next, you don't provide any context. At the most basic level, someone or something must execute your desired tsql statement against every "facility" database. There are different ways to accomplish that but they all fall back onto that same idea. So provide some context. Is this something you need to do from an application? Or is it something you need to do from SSMS (or similar tool)? And a simple example would do wonders to help others understand your goal.

Comment: Pulling data from 22 databases on the same server.  To me this is calling out for an SSIS package to query and combine the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CURSOR to achieve your requirement. Here I placed a sample Dynamic Insert Script which you can adjust as per your requirement. One manual task is you have to insert one by one 22 database name using script in a temporary table. The facility is that is is a one time work and you can re use the script when ever it is required.

```
--The first step will be creating a Table variable 
--where you will INSERT all your database names 
--for a further loop as below- 

DECLARE @DbName VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @DatabaseList TABLE (DbName VARCHAR(200))

INSERT INTO @DatabaseList (DbName) VALUES('db_name_1')
INSERT INTO @DatabaseList (DbName) VALUES('db_name_2')
--.......................
INSERT INTO @DatabaseList (DbName) VALUES('db_name_22')

--Now you can use CURSOR to generate the loop 
--and execute your required script as shown below

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT DbName FROM @DatabaseList

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @DbName  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

    --HERE You need to write your script That you
    --Execute for all your database. I have added
    --a sample script for your reference only

    -- You can see the Database Name inserted in the Script Dynamically from the Loop. 
    --The script could be INSERT/Update/DELETE As per requirement

    EXEC 
    (
        'INSERT INTO '+@DbName+'.dbo.<Your_table_Name_Here> 
        SELECT * FROM  master.dbo.<Your_table_Name_Here> '
    )

    --END OF Dynamic Part

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @DbName 
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```